# Django REST - How to make a test case that checks that a method is not allowed?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I have the following ModelViewSet:

```
class OrderViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
```

I would like to create four test cases:

- Check that (partial) updating is not allowed via OrderViewSet
- Check that listing is not allowed via OrderViewSet
- Check that retrieving is not allowed via OrderViewSet
- Check that deleting is not allowed via OrderViewSet

I'm facing a couple of issues. First, I'm unable to use reverse() for all of the test cases. The following test case works:

```
def test_disable_read_order_list(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('api:orders-list', kwargs={'currency': 'eur'}))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

When I try to use reverse to get the URL of the detail route:

```
reverse('api:orders-detail', kwargs={'currency': 'eur', 'pk': self.order.id})
```

I get:

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'orders-detail' not found. 'orders-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I have tried to hack around this by adjusting the URL that is used for the working test case:

```
def test_disable_read_order_detail(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('api:orders-list', kwargs={'currency': 'eur'}) + str(self.order.id) + '/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

but then statuscode 200 is returned for some reason.

What is the proper way to implement the unit tests I want?

Comment: Can you add views.py and urls.py files content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'orders-detail' not found. 'orders-detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` is a consequence of how `OrderViewSet` is implemented.

It's derived from `mixins.CreateModelMixin` and `viewsets.GenericViewSet` and hence enables creating orders, but nothing else (that's why `test_disable_read_order_list` passes).

You should get `404 Not Found`, unless `OrderViewSet` inherits from `mixins.RetrieveModelMixin`, when you try to request an order detail (say `/orders/1/`) and hence it's weird that you get `200 OK` in `test_disable_read_order_detail`.

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that in my urls.py I routed all urls that didnt match my API urls to the IndexView. I have changed that line to url('^(?!(?:api)/)', IndexView.as_view(), name='index') and now I get a proper 404.